# Sequelize multiple includes give wrong join query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In my domain model I have the following three models:

```
var challenge = sequelize.define('Challenge', {
    challengeId: {
        field: 'challenge_id',
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
    },
    ownerId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'USER', key: 'user_id'},
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        field: 'description',
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }
};

challenge.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'ownerId'});
challenge.hasMany(models.Idea, {foreignKey: 'challengeId'});

var idea = sequelize.define('Idea', {
  ideaId: {
    field: 'idea_id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    unique: true
  },
  challengeId: {
    field: 'challenge_id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'CHALLENGE', key: 'challenge_id'},
    allowNull: true
  },
  description: {
    field: 'description',
    type: DataTypes.STRING(600),
    allowNull: false
  }
};
idea.belongsTo(models.Challenge, {foreignKey: 'challengeId'});

var user = sequelize.define('User', {
  userId: {
    field: 'user_id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    unique: true
  },
  name: {
    field: 'name',
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}
user.hasMany(models.Challenge, {foreignKey: 'ownerId'});
```

This represents a simple domain model where a challenge is owned by a specific user. An idea is linked to one or zero challenges.

Now I would like to search for all challenges and also add a count of how many ideas are associated with that challenge. This query is something i got working, but as soon as i also want to include userinformation, the joins in the generated SQL are not correct.

To query the challenges and get a count of ideas I do this:

```
models.Challenge.findAll({
   attributes: ["Challenge.*", [models.sequelize.fn('COUNT', models.sequelize.col('Ideas.idea_id')), 'IdeaCount']],
   include: [{
      model: models.Idea,
      attributes: []
   }],
   group: ["Challenge.challenge_id"],
   order: [['count', 'ASC']]
}).then(function (rows) {
   console.log(rows)
 });
```

Which executes the correct SQL query:

```
SELECT "Challenge"."challenge_id" AS "challengeId", 
      "Challenge".*, 
       COUNT("Ideas"."idea_id")   AS "IdeaCount" 
FROM   "CHALLENGE" AS "Challenge" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "IDEA" AS "Ideas" 
                    ON "Challenge"."challenge_id" = "Ideas"."challenge_id" 
WHERE  "Challenge"."company_id" = 1 
GROUP  BY "Challenge"."challenge_id" 
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC;
```

Now when I want to also include information from the creator of the challenges, i get the wrong SQL.

```
models.Challenge.findAll({
   attributes: ["Challenge.*", [models.sequelize.fn('COUNT', models.sequelize.col('Ideas.idea_id')), 'IdeaCount']],
   include: [{
      model: models.Idea,
      attributes: []
   },
   {
      model: models.User,
      attributes: ["userId", "name"]
   }],
   group: ["Challenge.challenge_id"],
   order: [['count', 'ASC']]
}).then(function (rows) {
   console.log(rows)
 });
```

Which results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT "Challenge".*, 
    COUNT("Ideas"."idea_id") AS "IdeaCount", 
       "User".*
FROM   "CHALLENGE" AS "Challenge" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "IDEA" AS "Ideas" 
                    ON "Challenge"."challenge_id" = "Ideas"."challenge_id" 
       INNER JOIN "USER" AS "User" 
               ON "Challenge"."ownerId" = "User"."user_id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ("USER_ROLE" AS "User.Roles.USER_ROLE" 
                        INNER JOIN "ROLE" AS "User.Roles" 
                                ON "User.Roles"."role_id" = 
                                   "User.Roles.USER_ROLE"."feature_id") 
                    ON "User"."user_id" = "User.Roles.USER_ROLE"."user_id" 
WHERE  "Challenge"."company_id" = 1 
GROUP  BY "Challenge"."challenge_id" 
LIMIT  20;
```

Instead I would need an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT "Challenge".*, 
   "User"."user_id", 
   "User"."firstname", 
   "User"."lastname" 
FROM   (SELECT "Challenge".*, 
               COUNT("Ideas"."idea_id") AS "IdeaCount" 
        FROM   "CHALLENGE" AS "Challenge" 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN "IDEA" AS "Ideas" 
                            ON "Challenge"."challenge_id" = 
                               "Ideas"."challenge_id" 
        WHERE  "Challenge"."company_id" = 1 
        GROUP  BY "Challenge"."challenge_id") AS "Challenge" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "USER" AS "User" 
                    ON "User"."user_id" = "Challenge"."ownerId" 
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC 
LIMIT  20;
```

It seems like sequelize puts the left outer join for the user on the same level as the one that is used for counting the assocations. Instead, the join for the user information should happen outside of it. Is it possible to influence sequelize in such a way that this joins is done separately like is done as in the SQL statement described above?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?